# QT Creator release build QResource not found error

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to build a test application using QML `WebEngineView` using Qt Creator 5.15.
I have a folder inside `Resources/web/` where I have my HTML, JS and CSS files.
Inside the HTML file, I am loading other JavaScript and CSS files.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="qrc:/qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="qrc:/web/mytest.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="qrc:/web/mytest.css">
    <style>
```

When I build the QT Application as `Debug` then everything works fine.
But when I build the application as `Release` then I am able to load the index page but I get an error in the logs for JavaScript file.

```
QResource "/web/mytest.js" not found
```

In the debug build I don't get this error.
Any changes I need to do for the `Release` build?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your .pro file the following definition:

```
QTQUICK_COMPILER_SKIPPED_RESOURCES += your_resource.qrc
```

I have found solution at the end of this page:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/104692/qwebengineview-can-not-find-javascript-file-in-release-but-ok-in-debug/2

Related info in qt documentation at the end of this page:
https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qtwebengine-deploying.html